# My app jamming till my request finished in Xcode

Tags: php, xcode

I have an app that send PHP request in the ViewDidLoad to search any updated news. The problem with my code is that the app jamming till the request finished (you can not go back, or even press any button).

I am using the code below:

```
NSString *checkTitle = self.title;
    NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://MyWebSite/MyPHPFile.php?mytitle=%@",checkTitle];


NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest
                              requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                              queryString]
                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                              timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (con) {
_receivedData=[NSMutableData data];

[self bringData];
} else {
//something bad happened
}
```

What I need is to send request and in the same time (users) can use any other buttons.

Can any one help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSURLRequest *httpRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: queryString];

NSURLConnection *connection=[NSURLConnection
                             connectionWithRequest:httpRequest 
                             delegate:self];

[connection start];
```

Did you have implement delegate function for http request ?

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

Comment: Yes, I did implement delegate.

Comment: What about _receivedData=[NSMutableData data];

[self bringData]; from where do i need to call them